# Clear duplicates between columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I'm trying to get to loop through columns A and D until end.

If it finds a rows where 'A & D' are duplicates, I want it to leave the first instance, and clear the value in column 'D' for the duplicate rows.

So,

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
3 3 3 3  
1 1 1 1
```

Would become,

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 
1 2 2 2
3 3 3 3  
1 1 1
```

Heres the code so far,

```
Sub clearDups()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        For i = 1 To Lastrow
            If Cells(i, 1).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value And Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then
                Range("D" & i + 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    
    End Sub
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: load the whole range into a variant array.  Loop the "rows" of the variant array and using a dictionary test if it exists or not.  If not load the concatenated columns as the key into the dictionary.  If it does exist remove the item in the 4th "Column" of that "Row".  Then load the array back on top of the range.

Comment: Why don't you accurately explain when a row is considered a duplicate. You're writing about `A&D` yet your code is looking in `A&B`. Considering the former, e.g. `1,a,b,1` is a duplicate of `1,c,d,1`. Is that really the functionality you need? Also, there is too little sample data to draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplAD()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, arr, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 4)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 4), vbNullString 'only like reference. This row value in "D:D" will remain
        Else
            arr(i, 4) = ""   'value in "D:D" will be delete
        End If
   Next i
   sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Your code could not work. It has a chance to work (with some modifications) only if the duplicate lines are **consecutive**. The above code, modifies/clear the D:D contents only for the next occurrences, the first one remaining unmodified, independent of the its position/row in the range.